# How to center a widget inside a column inside of a SingleChildScrollView

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this screen with a searchWidget on top and a list below it. But the list data comes after querying in the `searchWidget`, and while waiting for the data to be fetched i want to render a `ActivityIndicator` at the center of the screen. But the progress indicator doesn't seem to take the rest of the space of the screen and it's directly below the `searchWidget`, and if i wrap it inside an `Expanded` it gives an error

```
body: SingleChildScrollView(
    physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
    child: Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      children: [
        SearchWidget(
            hintText: 'Search',
            textEditingController: _textEditingController,
            onCancel: () {
              setState(() {
                _textEditingController.text = '';
                data = [];
              });
            },
            onSubmitted: (val) {
              onSubmitted(val);
            }),
        _isLoading 
            ? (Container(
                child: Center(
                  child: CupertinoActivityIndicator(
                    radius: 15,
                  ),
                ),
              ))
            : (data.length == 0
                ? SizedBox()
                : Padding(
                    padding:
                        const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8, right: 8, left: 8),
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      itemCount: data.length,
                      itemBuilder: (ctx, i) =>
                          ListItem(item: data[i]),
                    ),
                  ))
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

[image]

Comment: Use Stack and Inside Stack out your `CupertinoActivityIndicator`

Answer (score 3):

Try Expanded:

```
    _isLoading 
        ? (Expanded(
            child: Center(
              child: CupertinoActivityIndicator(
                radius: 15,
              ),
            ),
          ))
```

Comment: It doesn't work. "RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded."

Comment: try to remove SingleChildScrollView

Answer (score 0):

Put your `CupertinoActivityIndicator` inside a `Column` and use `Spacer` to put it in the middle of the screen. Just like this:

```
Column(
  children: [
    Spacer(),
    Container(
      child: Center(
        child: CupertinoActivityIndicator(
          radius: 15,
         ),
       ),
      ),
     Spacer()
   ]
 )
```